# Sum of series with generic term inside it

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I have the following series:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} k \cdot a^k \cdot s_k
$$

Having $|a| < 1$ and where $s_k \in [0,1]$ is a generic sequence having the property for which $\lim_{k \to \pm\infty} s_k = 0$.

I know that:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} k \cdot a^k = \frac{a}{(a-1)^2}
$$

But how to handle $s_k$? Is there a method to find the sum of the first series? Thankyou!

Comment: Not unless you know a formula for the $s_k$

Answer (score 1):

No finite amount of $s_k$'s determine $\sum_{k=0}^\infty ka^ks_k$, hence any 'method' to evaluate this sum in terms of operations of finite arity, necessarily consists of infinitely many such operations. Thus in a sense, straightforwardly summing $\sum_{k=0}^\infty ka^ks_k$ is the easiest method possible.